# php alternative for javascript's Date().getTime()

Tags: php

With below javascript code I get timestamp

```
<script>
Date().getTime()
</script>
```

Which results in `1454497242551`

how can I get the same kinda timestamp via php

Comment: Check out the [microtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function. Note that it will return microseconds  since the Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1,1970 GMT) so you'll need to multiply by 1000 because the JavaScript's `Date().getTime()` returns it in milliseconds.

Comment: @mrun: surely, you mean ***divide*** by 1,000: 1 microsecond == .001 ms after all. Or you just get the unix timestamp (which counts the number of ***seconds*** since 1 jan 1970), by calling `time()`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yeah my bad! You're right of course!

Comment: @mrun: Honest mistake, we've all been there

Comment: can some one tell me why down votes

Comment: @Vishnu: in all likelihood the -1's are because this question basically is like asking: _"Here's some code in language X, can someone write it in language Y for me?"_ Translation-questions are down-vote magnets. You could've asked it slightly differently (ie: _"How do I get the timestamp in microseconds in PHP"_), and demonstrate a basic knowledge of PHP (you've only posted JS code here, you've not demonstrated you know about `time();` or `new DateTime();` in PHP)... just guessing here, but I think those probably are the reasons why you got down-voted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP and large integers seem to cause issues but perhaps you could try:

```
quick and easy way
-----------------
echo sprintf('%013.0f', microtime(1)*1000 );

alt version, but no more accurate
---------------------------------
$pieces = explode( " ", microtime() );
$ctstmp = bcadd( ( $pieces[0]*1000 ), bcmul( $pieces[1], 1000 ) );

echo $ctstmp;


In Javascript
var ts=new Date().getTime();


results:
--------
Javascript:      1454592264750
PHP ( sprintf ): 1454592264020
PHP ( alt ):     1454592264020
```

It is correct to multiply by 1000 because microtime(true) returns the Unix timestamp in seconds as a float and the javascript `new Date().getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since the DateTime epoch ( where they both use the epoch time of 1970/01/01 )

Ok, there is a difference between the PHP and the Javascript - that could be due to rendering on the page.

Comment: @mrun - have you tried in in comparison to the javascript `new Date().getTime()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `microtime()` function in PHP

```
echo microtime();
```

But, you'll need to divide it by 1000 (and `floor` the outcome).

Thanks to @mrun for pointing out!

Comment: but it displays just 1454497759 , i want full length like mentioned in question

Comment: Updated post, should be microtime() instead

Comment: Still wrong. Please take a look at my comment I left under the question.

Comment: @luweiqi: see my comment below the question: ***Divide*** by 1,000 not multiply. To get the milliseconds as an integer, you need to write `floor(microtime()/1000);`

Comment: Oh, I also didn't realise that, only realised after trying it myself, thanks! @EliasVanOotegem